# reference issue in updating JSON data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I need help in understanding the behaviour of JSON [reference issue].

```
var obj = {"newData":["Hello"]};

obj["oldData"] = obj.newData;
// Here added new key "oldData" 
// Expected output is coming: {"newData":["Hello"],"oldData":["Hello"]}

obj["newData"].push("hi");
// On updating "newData"
// Excepted Output                  : {"newData":["Hello","hi"],"oldData":["Hello"]}
// But Actual Output is coming as   : {"newData":["Hello","hi"],"oldData":["Hello","hi"]}
```

How to solve this issue.
How to avoid updating oldData field. [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/bcqcsp69/2/)

Same issue with objects, [jsfiddle example for objects](https://jsfiddle.net/bcqcsp69/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `obj["oldData"] = obj.newData;` you create a reference to your `newData` array so every change in `newData` will affect `oldData` array. Use `obj["oldData"] = obj.newData.slice();` instead, to create a clone of array so that there would be dwo different arrays.

Comment: what if there is a object instaed of array

Comment: then you wouldn't be able to use `.push` in your sample, we consider arrays in this case.

Comment: @DiveshOswal the point is that you need to copy it, to avoid the reference issue, the way for copying will depend on what it is..

Comment: @Kaddath    how to copy to avoid reference,  var a= b; isn't way of copy

Comment: @Divesh https://jsfiddle.net/bcqcsp69/3/ if you plan to have in your objects just simple values like 'a':'aa' (strings or numbers) you can copy all properties from one object `newData` to another `oldData`. When it comes to copy arrays or objects it's not so easy. You can use jQuery for that `var obj.oldData = jQuery.extend({}, obj.newData)`

Comment: you can also use `Object.assign()` javascript method  similarly like jquery `.extend()` but IE does not support this js method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `newData = Object.assign({}, oldData);`
And after change any of property of newDate without scaring to change oldDate the same...

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {"newData":["Hello"]};

obj["oldData"] = obj.newData.concat(); //make copy of array

obj["newData"].push("hi");
```

Comment: Care for some additional explanation (as asked for)? How exactly does it help? Have you taken into account that [`concat` returns a shallow copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)?